# Why did switching from Bootstrap 3.3.6 to 3.3.7 wreck the UI?

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Here are two images of a page of my app running under Bootstrap 3.3.6 and 3.3.7

[image: Bootstrap 3.3.6]

[image: Bootstrap 3.3.6]

For the record, my app is a Springboot app with Thymeleaf, JQuery, and Bootstrap. I would prefer to use the most recent version of Bootstrap if at all possible. 
Here's the html page in question:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4">
<head th:fragment="header">
    <meta charset="utf-8"></meta>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"></meta>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"></meta>
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <link rel="icon" href="/werewolf-512.png"></link>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css" th:href="@{/css/style.css}"></link>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/font-awesome.css" th:href="@{/css/font-awesome.css}"></link>
    <!-- Bootstrap & JQuery -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" th:href="@{/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css}"></link>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" th:href="@{/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css}"></link>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/webjars/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js" th:src="@{/webjars/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js}"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.7/bootstrap.min.js" th:src="@{/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js}"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js" th:src="@{/webjars/jquery-ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js}"></script>

    <script type="application/javascript" src="/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script> <!--  th:src="@{/webjars/ckeditor/4.5.8/standard/ckeditor.js}"></script> -->
    <script src="/ckeditor/gameserver/js/sample.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/ckeditor/gameserver/css/samples.css"></link>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/ckeditor/gameserver/toolbarconfigurator/lib/codemirror/neo.css"></link>

    <title th:text="#{editCampaign.title}">Title</title>

    <script th:inline="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $( window ).load(function() {
            var unselectedList = $("#unselectedTags")[0].value;
            var unselectedTagList = null;
            if (unselectedList.length > 0) {
                unselectedTagList = jQuery.parseJSON(unselectedList);
            } else {
                unselectedTagList= [];
            }

            var selectedList = $("#selectedTags")[0].value;
            var selectedTagList = null;
            if (selectedList.length > 0) {
                selectedTagList = jQuery.parseJSON(selectedList);
            } else {
                selectedTagList = [];
            }

            $.each(unselectedTagList, function(i, item) {
                var name = item["name"];
                var id = item["id"];
                var newButton = $('<button type="button"/>')
                  .text(name)
                  .click( function() { 
                        $("#addTag").val(id);
                        $("#editFolioForm").attr("action", "/shared/addRemoveTag");
                        $("#editFolioForm").submit();
                  })
                  .addClass("btn btn-default add-btn")
                  .attr('id', id)
                  .attr('name', name)
                  .appendTo($("#unselectedTagSpan"));
            });

            $.each(selectedTagList, function(i, item) {
                var name = item["name"];
                var id = item["id"];
                if (name == "Campaign Description") {
                    var newButton = $('<button type="button"/>')
                      .text(name)
                      .attr("disabled", "true")
                      .addClass("btn btn-default add-btn")
                      .attr('id', id)
                      .attr('name', name)
                      .appendTo($("#selectedTagSpan"));
                } else {
                    var newButton = $('<button type="button"/>')
                      .text(name)
                      .click( function() { 
                            $("#removeTag").val(id);
                            $("#editFolioForm").attr("action", "/shared/addRemoveTag");
                            $("#editFolioForm").submit();                         
                      })
                      .addClass("btn btn-default add-btn")
                      .attr('id', id)
                      .attr('name', name)
                      .appendTo($("#selectedTagSpan"));
                }
            });

            if ($("#isOwner").val() == "true") {
                var users = $("#users")[0].value;
                var userList = null;
                if (users.length > 0) {
                    userList = jQuery.parseJSON(users);
                }

                $.each(userList, function(i, item) {
                    var name = item["userName"];
                    var id = item["userId"];
                    var rowDiv = $('<div/>');
                    var access;
                    if (item["itemPermission"] == "PERMISSION_OWNER") {
                        access = "Owner";
                    } else if (item["itemPermission"] == "PERMISSION_READ_WRITE") { 
                        access = "Read/Write";
                    } else if (item["itemPermission"] == "PERMISSION_READ") {
                        access = "Read";
                    } else {
                        // in this case item["itemPermission"] == "NO_PERMISSION"
                        access = "No Access";
                    }
                    var button = $('<input id="'+id+'" type="button" class="permission" onclick="modifyPermission(&quot;'+id+'&quot;)"/>')
                        .prop("value", access);
                    button.appendTo(rowDiv);
                    var spacerDiv = $('<div class="small-spacer"/>');
                    spacerDiv.appendTo(rowDiv);
                    var label = $('<label class="input-margin"/>')
                        .text(name);
                    label.appendTo(rowDiv);
                    rowDiv.appendTo("#permissionList")
                });             
            } else {
                $("#permissionLabel").addClass("hide");
                $("#permissionList").addClass("hide");
            }
        }); 

        if ($("#folioId").val() == "") {
            $("#copyBtn").attr("hidden", "true");
        } 

        $("#editFolioForm").submit(function(event) {
            var permissionMap = {};
            var buttonMap = {};
            var buttonData = [];
            $('.permission').each(function(i, btn) {
                var value = $(this).attr("value");
                var id = $(this).attr("id");

                item = {};
                item["id"] = id;
                item["value"] = value;

                buttonData.push(item);

                buttonMap[id] = value;
            });
            console.log(buttonData);

            var usersObject = JSON.parse($("#users").val());
            $.each(usersObject, function(i, item) { 
                var userId = item["userId"];
                var newPermission = buttonMap[userId];
                if (newPermission == "Owner") {
                    item["itemPermission"] = "PERMISSION_OWNER";
                } else if (newPermission == "Read/Write") {
                    item["itemPermission"] = "PERMISSION_READ_WRITE";
                } else if (newPermission == "Read") {
                    item["itemPermission"] = "PERMISSION_READ";
                } else {
                    item["itemPermission"] = "NO_ACCESS";
                }
            });
            var newUserString = JSON.stringify(usersObject)
            $("#users").val(newUserString);
        });

        $("#changeView").click(function() {
            var cvValue = $("#changeView").attr("value");
            if (cvValue == "View as HTML") {
                var data = CKEDITOR.instances.editor.getData();
                $("#viewContainer").html(data);
                $("#viewContainer").removeClass("hide");
                $("#editorContainer").addClass("hide");
                $("#changeView").attr("value", "Edit");
                if ($("#isOwner").val() == "true") {
                    $("#permissionLabel").addClass("hide");
                    $("#permissionList").addClass("hide");
                }
                $("#submitBtn").addClass("hide");
            } else {
                $("#viewContainer").addClass("hide");
                $("#editorContainer").removeClass("hide");
                $("#changeView").attr("value", "View as HTML");
                if ($("#isOwner").val() == "true") {
                    $("#permissionLabel").removeClass("hide");
                    $("#permissionList").removeClass("hide");
                }
                $("#submitBtn").removeClass("hide");
            }
        });

        $("#copyBtn").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#folioId").val("");
            $("#folioStatus").text("You are editing a copied document");
            $("#pageTitle").val("");
        });
    });     
    </script>   

    <script th:inline="javascript">
        function selectFolio() {
            window.location = "/shared/selectFolio?operation=edit";
        }

        function modifyPermission(buttonId) {
            var button = $("#"+buttonId);
            var selection = button.attr("value");
            if (selection == "No Access") {
                button.prop("value", "Read");
            } else if (selection == "Read") {
                button.prop("value", "Read/Write"); 
            } else if (selection == "Read/Write") { 
                button.prop("value", "Owner");
            } else {
                button.prop("value", "No Access");
            }
        }

    </script>
    <script>
       $(function() {
          $("#addTagDialog" ).dialog({
             autoOpen: false,  
             buttons: {
               OK: function() {
                   $("#addTag").val($("#tagName").val());
                   $(this).dialog("close");
                   $("#editFolioForm").attr("action", "/shared/addTag");
                   $("#editFolioForm").submit();
               }
             }
          });

          $("#createTag").click(function() {
             $("#addTagDialog").dialog( "open" );
          });
       });
    </script>
</head>
<body id="main">
    <div th:include="/public/navbar :: navbar"></div>

    <br></br>
    <br></br>
    <br></br>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-1"></div>
        <div class="col-md-11">
            <h1 th:text="#{editFolio.title}">Updated</h1>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-1"></div>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <span class="error-message" th:if="${feFeedback.error}" th:text="${feFeedback.error}">Error.</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-1"></div>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <span class="info-message" th:if="${feFeedback.info}" th:text="${feFeedback.info}">Info.</span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <form id="editFolioForm" th:object="${folioDto}" action="#" th:action="@{/shared/editFolio}" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" id="campaignId" th:field="*{folio.campaignId}"></input>
        <input type="hidden" id="unselectedTags" th:field="*{unselectedTags}"></input>
        <input type="hidden" id="selectedTags" th:field="*{selectedTags}"></input>
        <input type="hidden" id="addTag" th:field="*{addTag}"></input>
        <input type="hidden" id="removeTag" th:field="*{removeTag}"></input>
        <input type="hidden" id="folioId" th:field="*{folio.id}"></input>
        <input type="hidden" id="operationType" th:field="*{operationType}"></input>
        <input type="hidden" id="users" th:field="*{users}"></input>
        <input type="hidden" id="isOwner" th:field="*{isOwner}"></input>
        <input type="hidden" id="forwardingUrl" th:field="*{forwardingUrl}"></input>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-1"></div>
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <hr></hr>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-1"></div>
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <button id="folioStatus" type="button" class="input-margin btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" aria-expanded="false" th:text="${feFeedback.userStatus}"></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-1"></div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <label class="input-margin" th:text="#{editFolio.selectFolio}">Select</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="btn-group">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" th:utext="#{editFolio.selectFolio}" th:onclick="'selectFolio();'">Select Folio</button>
                </div>              
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-1"></div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <label class="input-margin" th:text="#{editFolio.pageTitle}">Name</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <input id="pageTitle" class="input-margin fullWidth" th:field="*{folio.title}"></input>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="addTagDialog" title="Add a tag">
            <label for="tagName">New tag</label>
            <input id="tagName"></input>
        </div>  
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-1"></div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <label class="input-margin" th:text="#{editFolio.createTag}">Create</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <input type="button" id="createTag" class="input-margin" th:value="#{editFolio.createTagText}"></input>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-1"></div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <label class="input-margin" th:text="#{selectFolio.unselectedTags}">Tags</label>      
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">   
            <div class="col-md-1"></div>    
            <div class="row col-md-10">
                <span id="unselectedTagSpan"></span>
            </div>  
        </div>              

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-1"></div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <label class="input-margin" th:text="#{selectFolio.selectedTags}">Tags</label>    
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">   
            <div class="col-md-1"></div>    
            <div id="selectedTagSpan" class="row col-md-10">
            </div>  
        </div>          

        <div id="editorContainer" class="folio-margin">
            <div class="grid-container">
                <div class="grid-width-100">
                    <textarea id="editor" th:field="*{folio.content}"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-1"></div>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <div id="viewContainer" class="hide folio-margin"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-1"></div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <input type="button" id="changeView" class="basic-margin" value="View as HTML"></input>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="permissionLabel" class="row">
            <div class="col-md-1"></div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <label class="input-margin" th:text="#{editFolio.setPermissions}">Set</label>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="permissionDiv" class="row">
            <div class="col-md-1"></div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="panel panel-primary">
                    <div class="panel-body permissionListPanel">
                        <span id="permissionList"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>  
            </div>
        </div>                          
        <br></br>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-1"></div>
            <div class="col-md-7">
                <input type="button" id="copyBtn" class="basic-margin" value="Copy"></input>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-1"></div>
            <div class="col-md-7">
                <input id="submitBtn" class="basic-margin" type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </div>
        </div>

    </form>

    <script>
    <!-- ckeditor js code -->
        initSample();
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is the new Bootstrap CSS file being loaded by your browser? It could be a caching issue.

Comment: Yea, it doesn't even look like it's being loaded.

Comment: Looks like you folks are right. This was apparently a cache issue. Thanks.